# ¿Cómo clasifico los datos según la fecha?

Tags: excel

tengo un conjunto de datos con una fecha asociada a cada uno en una tabla. El problema viene que no soy capaz de, como hay fechas que se saltan, clasificar cada dato, que tiene una fecha asociada, con las fechas generales de la columna de la izquierda del todo.

Un saludo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta es un poco difusa. ¿A qué te refieres con *clasificar cada dato, que tiene una fecha asociada, con las fechas generales de la columna de la izquierda del todo*? ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo a mano del resultado que esperas conseguir?

Comment: Claro que si, lo que busco es que los datos de las columnas Fecha y ADJ CLOSE se organicen del estilo: el 3'856391 corresponde con el 15-09-2021, pues poner el 3'856391 al lado del 15-09-2021 de la columna fecha real

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes hacerlo usando SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO:

> [Función
> SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/funci%C3%B3n-sumar-si-conjunto-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

En la imagen se ve el mismo conjunto de datos 2 veces: el de arriba es un rango normal y el de abajo tiene formato tabla.

Si es un rango normal, esta fórmula te sirve:

```
=SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO($D$2:$D$14;$C$2:$C$14;A2)
```

Si lo tienes como formato tabla, en ese caso no se usan referencias a las celdas sino a los campos definidos, pero la fórmula es la misma:

```
=SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO([ADJ];[Fecha];[@[Fecha real]])
```

Verás que las fechas de FECHA REAL que no aparecen en FECHA devuelven 0.

Answer (score 0):

Como complemento a la respuesta de Esei, si tuvieras la certeza que los valores en la columna "Fecha" no se repiten también puedes utilizar un **buscarv**

```
=BUSCARV(A2;C:D;2;FALSO)
```

El **buscarv** también sería la solución cuando los valores de la columna ADJ fueran texto. Pero... OJO, te mostraría el primer valor encontrado empezando la búsqueda desde la fila superior.